# How to add to the list item when click button in xamarin

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios, xamarin-studio

Here is my modal in xamarin:

```cs
public AboutPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    AddProductCommand = new Command<Product>(AddProduct);
    this.BindingContext = this;
}

public ObservableCollection<Product> AllProducts { get => GetProduct(); }
public ObservableCollection<Product> AddedProducts { get; } = new ObservableCollection<Product>();

public ICommand AddProductCommand { get; }

private ObservableCollection<Product> GetProduct()
{
    return new ObservableCollection<Product>
    {
        new Product { id=1, Type = "Drink", Name = "Cola", Stock = 123 },
    };
}

public void AddProduct(Product newProduct)
{
    AddedProducts.Add(newProduct);
}
```

And here is my view:

```xml
<DataTemplate>
    <pv:PancakeView BackgroundColor="#EEF2FF" VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand" 
            HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
        <Grid ColumnSpacing="3" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <BoxView Grid.RowSpan="1" BackgroundColor="#EEF2FF"/>
            <BoxView Grid.Column="1" Grid.RowSpan="1" BackgroundColor="#EEF2FF"/>
            <BoxView Grid.Column="2" Grid.RowSpan="1" BackgroundColor="#EEF2FF"/>
            <Label Text="#" HorizontalOptions="Fill"  Grid.Column="0" HorizontalTextAlignment="Left" Padding="0, 0, 0, 10" VerticalTextAlignment="Center"/>
            <Label Text="{Binding Type}" HorizontalOptions="Fill" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalTextAlignment="Left" VerticalTextAlignment="Center"/>
            <Label Text="{Binding Name}" HorizontalOptions="Fill" Grid.Column="2" HorizontalTextAlignment="Left" VerticalTextAlignment="Center"/>
            <Label Text="{Binding Stock}" HorizontalOptions="Fill" Grid.Column="3" HorizontalTextAlignment="Left" VerticalTextAlignment="Center"/>
        </Grid>
    </pv:PancakeView>
</DataTemplate>
```

Here is my button which are being displayed from the Product list in my modal.

```xml
<Button
    Text="{Binding Name}"
    Grid.Column="0"
    HorizontalOptions="Center"
    VerticalOptions="Center"
    TextColor="Black"
    BackgroundColor="#EEF2FF"
    Command="{Binding AddProductCommand}"
    CommandParameter="{Binding .}" />
```

So buttons are the Products such as Cola, Water, Soda etc that you can see in my modal. AddedProducts is the list that I want to display in PancakeView. So when I click Cola button, I want to add it to the list and show it on the list which is inside of the PancakeView.

I hope I am clear, I am quite new in xamarin so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: you already have a method `Handle_AddProduct` - does that not do what you want?

Comment: No it doesnt. So when I click the first button which is new Product { id=1, Type = "Drink", Name = "Cola", Stock = 123 }, I want to add this Product to the list

Comment: if you are trying to bind `Handle_AddProduct` to a Command, then it needs to be a public Command property

Comment: I edited my question, can you look at it one more time?

Comment: This code looks like it should work, does it?

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesnt. It doesnt include anything on my list and also no error

Answer (score 0):

the signature of your command needs to match the parameter

```
<Button ...
    Command="{Binding AddProductCommand}"
    CommandParameter="{Binding .}" />
```

so the command should look like

```
public Command<Product> AddProductCommand { get; set; }
```

you also need to assign some action to the command to make it actually do something

```
AddProductCommand = new Command<Proudct>(
        execute: (Product arg) =>
        {
            // do something here
        });
```

Comment: So should I delete the AddProduct function? and I didnt understand really how can I add this button properties into my list?

Comment: you can call `AddProduct` from the Command.  `arg` is the `Product` you are passing from your Button binding